# Soft delete a document from mongoose db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a function that creates coupon codes. I added an expiry date on a field that will automically expire the coupon as per the date stated. For this I used mongoose TTL property. But my issue goes that it removes the document permanently from the database.

Here's my schema and controller for the same:

```
const promotionalCodeSchema = new schema({

    promoCodeName: { 
        type: String,
    },
    promoCodeType: String,
    expired: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    amount: String,
    isActive: { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: true 
    }, 
    user_id: ObjectId,
    expirationDate: {
        type: Date,
        expires: 0,
        unique: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


async createPromoCode(req, res) {
    let body = req.body;

    try {
      let newObjBody = {
        promoCodeName: "",
        promoCodeType: "",
        amount: "",
        expirationDate:{
            expires:0
        }
      };

      newObjBody.amount = body.promoAmount;
      newObjBody.isActive = body.promoActive;
      newObjBody.promoCodeName = PromotionalCodeController.generateCoupon();

      newObjBody.promoCodeType = body.promoCodeType;

      let days = parseInt(body.promoExpiry.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ""));
      newObjBody.expirationDate = new Date(Date.now() + (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

      const promotionalcodeschema = new PromotionalCodeSchema(newObjBody);
      await promotionalcodeschema.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).json({err})
        } else {
          res.status(201).json(result)
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Everything is working fine but I need to only update the document's property to be 'expired: true', when the expiry date is reached but not get it erased permanently from the database.

Please help me suggest a proper way to achieve the same.

Comment: I can only guess but is you `days` the days until the code expires? 
If yes, you can `if (days ==0){newObjBody.expired= true}`

But you may need this also in you mongoose model scheme

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Can you please explain this a bit more elaborately? On how I can add this in my schema?

Comment: Ah I didn't see, its already in your Schema. So is `days` the amount of days until the code expires? If so, you can set the `expired` to `true` when `days` are zero.

Comment: Yes, `days` is the number of days after which the coupon expires. But `expires` property deletes the document from the database completely/permanently. Are you sure setting `expired: true` will not delete the document permanently from database?

Comment: If setting the `promoCodeName`, the `amount` and all the other things in you `newObjBody` to values is working, then why should setting `expires=true` delete everything?

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel I have not tested `expires=true` yet. I created this function without it first and checked my database. It was deleting the coupon as soon as the expiry of say, 2 days was matched. After that, I thought of adding a property `expire` ( maybe it could prevent permanent deletion) but not sure if that will fulfill my requirement. That's why just confirming from you.

Comment: sorry i had a typing mistake: add a property called `expired` (which you already have in your `promotionalCodeSchema ` but not in your `newObjBody`). Set it to true, if the amount of days is equal zero

Comment: Okay. I will try it out and will update if it solved my problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212158/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-alexander-riedel).